# Generate document with plots based on template, Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, reporting, pyqt4

I have a Python3 GUI, where user selects certain values to be statistically evaluated and/or plotted (hist).

Out of this GUI on users request I want to create a report, prefferebly in DOC or/and ODT or/and PDF formats. The layout of the report is pretty much fixed, what will change is: the names of the selected measures and the corresponding values (there are always three measures to display - user selects which), matplotlib histogram (will change depending on the selected settings), user name, date etc.

In some older thread I found a reference to [pod](http://appyframework.org/pod.html) package which looks very close to my needs. But I didn't find any good illustration of the resulting documents. And what is most important, I'm not sure if images are allowed there - I would imagine reserving a place for the image somewhere in the corner of the document and update it when user request the report.

**EDIT1**: [pod](http://appyframework.org/pod.html) does NOT support Python3, also after 2to3 convertion and couple of small fixes. There was an advice to use LaTeX, but I'm not sure I understand how to implement this idea without going to the very low level of coding.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated since the rest of the project is nearly done and this is the last big unsolved problem.

**EDIT2**: After some break I return to this problem. Since my GUI is in PyQt4, I finally decided to go with QTextDocument and print document to PDF. There are some unclear moments for me in this approach, like if I should use QTextCursor and programically create the document or create somehow HTML first. Also, I have to figure out how to create the document without displaying editor window. Any references with examples are welcome. So far I found only couple of examples in PyQt4\examples\richtext, but they don't answer all my questions.

Comment: Is a LaTeX dependency acceptable?

Comment: I would avoid extra dependency, but if there are certain advantages of this approach - yes, Latex is acceptable. More important is that I would ideally like to see the template editable by the user, and at this point I don't want any Latex dependency. The user is not supposed to be technically advanced.

Comment: Oh, the user is supposed to edit the template?  That's a completely different story.  Do you think your users would be able to cope with some kind of tailored XML format?

Comment: Well, the very end user probably not. But I have an intermediate user who would like to configure that a little bit without askig myself for every little change. But that is realy optional. That is why I said "idelly" :)

Comment: Most of the best-known Python PDF generation libraries don't seem to have been ported to Python 3.x yet, so unless someone knows a better solution, you might have to use LaTeX for now.

Comment: How should I use Latex for that? Print Latex comands into the file and compile then? Can I compile it automatically from Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem. It was not so difficult at the end, and I ended up using QTextDocument and its setHtml method to produce the desired document. Related question with the code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294692/how-to-set-qtextdocument-margins-and-other-properties-sethtml-print-to-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I try to look at ReportLab now - it doesn't provide DOC (only PDF), but seems to be flexible. As I learned from [FAQ](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/faq/#2.1.3), images are allowed, but I will have to save them from matplotlib in jpeg first (PIL is not available for Python3 yet). I hope I will not end up with extreme low level programming for report creation...

Comment: I would have recommended ReportLab if their [download page](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/download/) wouldn't state it works on Python 2.x only.

Comment: Since you are using matplotlib (you didn't mention so far), you might want to have a look at [this FAQ entry on saving multiple plots to a PDF file](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/howto_faq.html#save-multiple-plots-to-one-pdf-file).

Comment: oh, thanks for reminder to check Python3 support - something i didn't look at... and look at your link, thank you!