# How to set QTextDocument margins and other properties (setHTML, print to pdf)?

Tags: html, qt4, python-3.x, pyqt4

I have the following `certificate` class for producing pdf document out of some images and data. After setting image sources, I call `generate()` function and get test.pdf output file. The document is created based on `QTextDocument` class using `setHtml(html)` method.

The problem is that I have huge white spaces around the document, while I want the title 'REPORT' with logo image to be on the very top of the page. I would also like to add lower border to the table, but as I understand it is not supported by Qt ([Supported HTML Subset](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html)).

Python3 code:

```
class certificate:

def __init__(self):
    self.logo = None
    pdffile = 'test.pdf'
    self.histogram = None
    self.printer = QPrinter()
    self.printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.Letter)
    self.printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    self.printer.setOutputFileName(pdffile)

def generate(self):
    document = QTextDocument()
    html = ""
    html += ('<head><title>Report</title><style></style></head>'
                 '<body><table width="100%"><tr>'
                    '<td><img src="{}" width="30"></td>'
                    '<td><h1>REPORT</h1></td>'
                 '</tr></table>'
                 '<p align=right><img src="{}" width="300"></p>'
                 '<p align=right>Sample</p></body>').format(self.logo, self.histogram)
    document.setHtml(html)
    document.print_(self.printer)
```

I never extensively used html before and never worked with QTextDocument, and would appreciate any advice on how to control document margins and table properties.

Other related property I want to control is resolution - I use pixel image size and need to know page and margin sizes in pixels.

**EDITED:** The question is almost answered by @mata. I can set now any margins and resolution, but do not understand how to control image and font sizes. E.g. if I need that an image is always 50mm wide, and html header and main text font sizes are visually the same - how to implement it?

**EDITED2:** The last part is solved too. Here is modified code by @mata, it gives the same result for any `dpi` value:

```
dpi=96

document = QTextDocument()
html = """
<head>
    <title>Report</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="{0}" width="{1}"></td>
            <td><h1>REPORT</h1></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <p align=right><img src="{2}" width="{3}"></p>
    <p align=right>Sample</p>
</body>
""".format('D:\Documents\IST Projects\diashape\docbook\Installation\images\istlogo_medium.png',
              40*dpi/96, 
              'D:\Documents\IST Projects\diashape\docbook\Installation\images\istlogo_medium.png', 
              200*dpi/96)

document.setHtml(html)

printer = QPrinter()
font = QFont()
font.setPointSize(12*dpi/96)
document.setDefaultFont(font)
printer.setResolution(dpi)
...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify what resolution you want to use in the constructor when you create the QPrinter.
Then after you've set the pagesize, you can use `width`, `height` and `resolution` on the printer to fint out that values, here's what I got for *Letter* (dpi-values can be different, they depend on the screen or the printer):

```
QPrinter(QPrinter.ScreenResolution)   #   96dpi,  752x992
QPrinter(QPrinter.PrinterResolution)  #   72dpi,  564x744
QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)     # 1200dpi, 9400x12400
```

You can also set the dpi directly using `setResolution`.
The size returned by width and height is the page size (same as pageRect().size()), which ist not the same as the paper size - as the page also has margins, which you can set like this:

```
printer.setPageMargins(12, 16, 12, 20, QPrinter.Millimeter)
```

this sets left and right margins to 12mm, top to 16mm and bottom to 20mm - just for example, if you want less white space you can obviously just use smaller values.
And you should set the document size to the size of the resulting size:

```
document.setPageSize(QSizeF(printer.pageRect().size()))
```

as you've noticed yourself, the subset of html and css allowed is very limited, specially for formatting tables. But instead of using a lower border on the table you could just use a hr, which probably will look like you want it.
At least it doesn't look that bad if I test it like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

a=QApplication([])
document = QTextDocument()
html = """
<head>
    <title>Report</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="{}" width="30"></td>
            <td><h1>REPORT</h1></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <p align=right><img src="{}" width="300"></p>
    <p align=right>Sample</p>
</body>
""".format('', '')

document.setHtml(html)

printer = QPrinter()
printer.setResolution(96)
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.Letter)
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf")
printer.setPageMargins(12, 16, 12, 20, QPrinter.Millimeter)
document.setPageSize(QSizeF(printer.pageRect().size()))
print(document.pageSize(), printer.resolution(), printer.pageRect())

document.print_(printer)
```

Comment: Thank you for a great example! Am I right that by changing the resolution all font sizes alse change? At least I see the difference when I change from 96 to 200 resolution. Is there any way to make everything in relative size? Or should I use absolute sizes and always recalculate them from the page size? Is `pageRect()` the size of the rect with text excluding margins (in pixels)? Why changing image width to "30%" makes it so wierd (out of page)?

Comment: - yes, changing the dpi will result in the text and images being a different size relative to the page, as the size of the elements (in pixels) stays the same while havint more pixels per page.

- it seems that the size attributes in the qt-html have to be absolute, there is also no mentioning of relative image sizes in the documentation. that's why it doesn't look right.

- `pageRect()` returns what you get when you subtract the margins from `paperRect()` (in _DevicePixel_).

Comment: if you wanted to use more flexible html, then you could use a QWebView (from QtWebKit if installed) to render the html, altough the rendering probably will be much slower - which could be a problem it you try to print the page before it's fully rendered.