# Better way to generate PDF from python3

Tags: pdf, python-3.x, pyqt, reporting

My application is using PyQt4 and Python3 (I dont know how to backport it to python2.7). I have a need to export PDF and also print to paper. My search for reporting tool ended nowhere, since ReportLab nor POD support python3. Somehow, I managed to create PDF files with this kind of...hassle.

```
tekstStampa = (str("%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%sIme stranke:     %s%sBroj predmeta: %s%sSudski broj:      %s%s%sPredmet otvoren: %s%sDatum rasprave:  %s u %s sati%s%sStatus stranke:    %s%sStatus predmeta: %s%sTip postupka:       %s%sVrednost spora:   %s dinara.%s%sSud:                      %s%sSudska jedinica:   %s%sSudija:                  %s%s%sNapomena: %s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s" %
            (zaglavlje1,'<br>',zaglavlje2,'<br>',zaglavlje3,'<br>',zaglavlje4,'<br>','<br>',
            linija,'<br>','<br>','<br>',prazno50,zaglavlje5,brPredmeta,'<br>',prazno51,'<font size="1">datum štampanja: ',datumStampe,'</font><br>','<br>',
            tempime, '<br>',brPredmeta,'<br>', tempsudskibr,'<br>','<br>',
            tempdatumtuzba, '<br>', tempdatumRas,tempvreme,'<br>','<br>',
            tempstatusstr,'<br>',tempstatusPredmeta,'<br>',temptip,'<br>',tempvrednost,'<br>','<br>',
            tempsud,'<br>',tempsudska,'<br>',tempsudija,'<br>','<br>',
            '<br>',tempnapomena,'<br>','<br>',
            linija, '<br>', '<br>',futer1,'<br>',
            futer2,'<br>',
            futer3,'<br>',
            futer4,'<br>',
            futer5,'<br>',)))

            self.ui.textStampa.setHtml(str(tekstStampa).replace('\\n','\r'))
```

As you can see, it's pretty messy, but the output looks acceptable. Not quite good, only acceptable. [Example](http://ge.tt/99iWiaK/v/0)

Now, I need to generate something [like this](http://ge.tt/9g2vvTL/v/0). Columns should be placed in fixed positions, column width is pre-determined. Rows are generated from list, which is queried from database. Quering is fine, I can get the data, but PAGE FORMATTING is killing me.

I have tried to use HTML tags (namely PRE for preformatted text, but it looks ugly) but I wasn't able to accomplish what I wanted.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok, I found something useful; it's possible (duh!) to write plain HTML and format it like that. Nice!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263556/generate-document-with-plots-based-on-template-python3

Comment: This one is solved. Using HTML syntax, putting it into QTextEdit, and then printing it is the way to go.

Comment: After a few hours, SO should let you post an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for tuple in sviaktivni: # extract variables from list of tuples
            tempid,ime,brPredmeta,statusStr,sudskiBr ,sudija ,datumRasprave, vreme, zaduzen,datumZaduzenja = tuple
            brojac +=1
            tekst = ('<html><head><title></title>' #variable which contains HTML tables
                        '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>'
                        '<style></style>'
                        '</head>'
                        '<body>'
                            '<table align ="center" border="0" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed">'
                                '<tr height="10%">'
                                        '<td  align="left" width="3%">'+str(brojac)+' </td>'
                                        '<td  align="left" width="15%">'+ime+' </td>'
                                        '<td  align="left" width="10%"> '+brPredmeta+' </td>'
                                        '<td  align="left" width="10%"> '+statusStr+' </td>'
                                        '<td  align="left" width="10%"> '+sudskiBr+' </td>'
                                        '<td  align="left" width="18%"> '+sudija+' </td>'
                                        '<td  align="left" width="15%"> '+zaduzen+' </td>'
                                        '<td  align="left"> '+datumZaduzenja+' </td>'
                                    '</tr>'
                            '</table>'
                        '</body>'
                    '</html>')

            self.ui.textStampa.append(tekst) #append with every iteration
```